# Enabling and disabling checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

basically I have a form of four HTML checkboxes. If the one with value "one" is ticked I want to disable the one with value "two" and visa versa. The rest of the checkboxes operate as normal.

I've almost got it there but when I untick the box it doesn't re-enable the other again.

HTML

```
<form>

<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="one">

<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="two">

<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="three">

<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="four">

</form>
```

Script

```
$( "input" ).change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();

    if(val == "one") {

     $("input[value='two']").prop( "disabled", true );

  }

  else if(val== "two") {

    $("input[value='one']").prop( "disabled", true );

  }

    });
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/znx4agwc/24/)

Comment: You're sure it's not possible to use inputs of the type 'radio'? These will function like you want natively. See: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_radio

Comment: @KIKOSoftware You cannot unselect a radio group once you've picked one, that is the difference.

Comment: @connexo: True, but you could use a third option for that. However, user1837290 want to disable and enable the input, that's different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(this).is(":checked")` to assign on `prop("disabled"..`

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    if (val == "one") {

      $("input[value='two']").prop("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));

    } else if (val == "two") {

      $("input[value='one']").prop("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="one">

  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="two">

  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="three">

  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="four">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work our for you:
[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/znx4agwc/43/)

```js
$( "input" ).change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();

 if(val == "one") {
   if(!$("input[value='two']").is('[disabled]')){   
     $("input[value='two']").prop( "disabled", true );
     }else{
      $("input[value='two']").prop( "disabled", false );
     }
    
  
  }
  
  else if(val== "two") {
   if(!$("input[value='one']").is('[disabled]')){
    $("input[value='one']").prop( "disabled", true );
   }else{
     $("input[value='one']").prop( "disabled", false );
    }
  }

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="one">

<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="two">

<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="three">

<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="four">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the current state of the checkbox.  To accomplish that, you can use the function **[`$.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)** along with the flag `:checked`

*This alternative uses **[`data-attribute`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** to make it shorter.*

With **[`data-attribute`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** you're not mixed up the values and the logic to disable/enable other checkboxes.  Therefore, the checkboxes can handle any values avoiding modifications in your disable/enable logic.

```js
// This way, you're separating the disable/enable logic.
$("input").change(function() {
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  if (target) $("input[data-disenable='" + target + "']").prop("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" data-disenable='1' data-target='2' value="one">
  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" data-disenable='2' data-target='1' value="two">
  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="three">
  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="four">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've almost got it there but when I untick the box it doesn't re-enable the other again.

You haven't handled that case in your handler, all of your calls to `prop` use `true` as the value (e.g., they all disable).

Instead, use `this.checked` to use `true` when the current checkbox is checked, or `false` when it isn't:

```js
$("input").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    if (val == "one") {
        $("input[value='two']").prop("disabled", this.checked);
    }
    else if (val == "two") {
        $("input[value='one']").prop("disabled", this.checked);
    }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="one">
  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="two">
  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="three">
  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="four">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

We can also make that a bit shorter, since the two branches do exactly the same thing, just with different selectors:

```js
$("input").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val === "one" || val === "two") {
      var other = val == "one" ? "two" : "one";
      $("input[value='" + other + "']").prop("disabled", this.checked);
    }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="one">
  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="two">
  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="three">
  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="four">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or we could even do it so that the HTML defines the relationship between the checkboxes using a `data-*` attribute:

```js
$("input").change(function() {
    var other = $(this).attr("data-disable");
    if (other) {
        $("input[value='" + other + "']").prop("disabled", this.checked);
    }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <!-- NOTE the data-disable attributes -->
  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="one" data-disable="two">
  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="two" data-disable="one">
  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="three">
  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="four">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(Note: You could also use [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) here, but there's no reason to unless you need the additional features it adds. It's **not** just an accessor for `data-*` attributes; it's both more and less than that.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "input" ).change(function(e) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val == "one") {
        $("input[value='two']").prop( "disabled", e.target.checked );
    }

    else if(val== "two") {
        $("input[value='one']").prop( "disabled", e.target.checked );
    }
});
```

this will do the magic

pay attention: you should pass `e` - event argument, and check its state `e.target.checked`